# Linux command-line .flac tag editor

Tags: linux, music, id3, metadata-editor, flac

I need a Linux bash program that will enable me to type a command that will edit the tags of a .flac file. I've learned so far how to use [id3v2](http://id3v2.sourceforge.net/) and [eyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/) but I've found them to not be fully compatible with .flac files.

**Explanation**: I use Rhythmbox to play my music and if I view a tagged .flac file with the command `id3v2 -l myfile.flac`, it returns me that the file is not tagged at all but in the Rhythmbox music player I do see tags.

*Edit:* I also could have used a specific music database which can tell me what is the composer of the songs. If I had find a suitable database I would have used the software called "picard" in which you can edit the URL of the database you would like to use.
*Therefore*, If someone here knows an online free database which holds a composer tag for the songs it could be even more helpful.

Comment: and by the way: it would help if you let us know with which program (better the exact command) the file was tagged!

Comment: I used the rhythmbox GUI to edit the tags for these .flac files and I've checked the version's issue and that's not the solution. I typed: `id3v2 -C mysong.flac` and after that the same command with `-l` instead and still the output was: `No ID3 tag`

Comment: id3v2 is specifically for mp3 files - FLAC tags are conceptually similar but stored differently technically.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by MusicBrainz not being a suitable database - MusicBrainz *is* an online database and is free to use - do you perhaps have special requirements that does not fit the licensing offered by MusicBrainz?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FLAC files, although they can in principle contain ID3 tags, officially employ Vorbis comments of Flac Tags. See [the official FLAC website](https://xiph.org/flac/faq.html#general__tagging) for the reference.

The [`metaflac`](https://xiph.org/flac/documentation_tools_metaflac.html) utility should be able to read/modify/write the FLAC file metadata, along with any other tool that can edit vorbis comments (such as the reference tool `vorbiscomment` which is part of [`vorbis-tools`](https://wiki.xiph.org/Vorbis-tools)).

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend a tool that can takes the open data from [Musicbrainz](https://musicbrainz.org/) into account.

Best MusicBrainz client is [Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/) but that's a GUI application, where you seek something for the command-line.

If you *sometimes* want to skip the GUI, then maybe [Operon](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/commands/operon.html) (part of music player Quod Libet, and in Debian and derived distributions part of package [exfalso](https://packages.debian.org/exfalso)) might be suitable for you.

If you want to locally rip and auto-tag full albums, then I recommend [whipper](https://github.com/whipper-team/whipper/).  Other similar but more sloppy tools are [abcde](https://abcde.einval.com/) and [ripit](http://www.ripit.pl/ripit/news.php).

For only tagging, but still oriented towards full albume, there is [Flactag](http://flactag.sourceforge.net/).